# How to optimize joined query to find obsolete data

Tags: soql, performance

We have a query to find and remove the obsolete data which looks like this:

```
select Id,Name from Matter__c 
where Id NOT IN (select Matter_Number_Lookup__c from Matter_Sitting__c)
```

So if a matter record is not linked by any matter sitting record, it can be considered as obsolete.

As there are one million records in both matter and matter sitting table, this query is very slow. Is there any way I can optimize this query?

Comment: That would be a non-selective query that would require a table scan. You want to avoid any kind of a "NOT IN" or "NOT =" in a query. If you can find a way to change that to an "IN", "Includes", etc, you'll be further along. Also, being able to use any kind of field that's indexed will make your query more selective to avoid having to perform a record by record table scan.

Comment: @crmprogdev Thank you for your comment. I know this is bad. I got the same feeling as you when I got this piece of code. But I just can find a better way to resolve this current situation. Try putting anything into a container will probably exceeds the soql limit.

Comment: were matters and their corresponding matter_number_lookups created in the same year/month?  This would give you a field to index on. I assume you are executing this in a batch start() method